# Simple ng-Repeat for options of Select boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using [ng-repeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to simple put down options from an array. Though, I hope I am doing it alright I am not able to see any options in the dropdown of select options. Can someone help me find the error?

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       
    $scope.Country = [
        "India","Pakistan","Germany"
    
    ];
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <select>
      <option ng-repeat="x in Country"></option>
     </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<option ng-repeat="x in Country">{{x}}</option>` You are not printing value thats it!

Comment: @Eric - How do you make these snippets out of the code? I too want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:::

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model ="selectedCountry">
        <option ng-repeat="x in Country" value = "{{x}}"> {{x}} </option>
    </select>

    <script>
         var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.Country = [
              "India","Pakistan","Germany"

            ];
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will create 3 select inputs..Not 3 options!

Comment: Yes Roy, it worked with edit of what Rayon Said ... ;) You were nearly there ....

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not printing any value into option element, you should try like below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="x in Country" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <script>
         var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.Country = [
             {"id":"1","name":"India"},
             {"id":"2","name":"Pakistan"},
             {"id":"3","name":"Germany"}
            ];
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` instead of using `ng-repeat` with select tag:

```
<select ng-options="x for x in country" ng-model="selectedCountry"> </select>
```

Comment: Oh yep, Got it! ... Thnx ;)

Comment: <select ng-options="option.name for option in Country track by option.id" ng-model="selectedCountry"></select>   Please look at my post. My solution is tested and valided

Answer (score 0):

yes you didn't use {{x}} this value that is the reason it's not working for you , it may be ng-options or option anything any thing you can use ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options` instead of using `ng-repeat` with select tag:

**My solution is tested and valided:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="option.name for option in Country track by option.id" ng-model="selectedCountry">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>

    ID: {{selectedCountry.id}} and NAME: {{selectedCountry.name}}

    <script>
         var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

         $scope.selectedCountry="";

         $scope.Country = [
             {"id":"1","name":"India"},
             {"id":"2","name":"Pakistan"},
             {"id":"3","name":"Germany"}
            ];
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjlPPnew4KyE3oMFlYwO)